# UI-Router url section being treated as parameter on refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using angularJS and UI-`Router`, I have some routes set up.

However, one one of the routes (`/events/create`), the "create" section of the URL is created as a parameter for another of my routes, instead of resolving to the correct declared address.

Any idea how I can resolve this?

events.js

```
angular.module('events', [
    'events.show',
    'events.create',
])
;
```

events-create.js

```
angular.module('events.create', [

])
.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('sb.events.create', {
            url: '/events/create',
            views: {
                'forms@': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/events/create/event-create.tmpl.html',
                    controller: 'EventsCreateCtrl as createCtrl',
                },
                'main@': {

                }
            },
        })
})
```

finally, events-show.js

```
angular.module('events.show', [

])
.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('sb.events.show', {
            url: 'events/{eventId}',
            views: {
                'forms@': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/events/show/event-show.tmpl.html',
                    controller: 'EventsShowCtrl as showCtrl',
                },
                'main@': {

                }
            },
        })
})
.controller('EventsShowCtrl', 
    function EventsShowCtrl($state, $stateParams, EventsModel, UserModel, $rootScope) {

})

;
```

As you can see, events.show declares a parameter to be used. This is the state which is used for the url `events/create` on refresh or direct access to the url.

If I navigate to this state the normal way, the correct state and template is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6w6kTOBEXndB1X57zYKJ?p=preview). The way how to solve it, is to change the order of declarations

Be sure that this state

```
.state('sb.events.create', {
    url: '/events/create',
```

is registering (executing of the `$stateProvider.state()`) sooner, before this

```
.state('sb.events.show', {
    //url: 'events/{eventId}',
    url: '/events/{eventId}',
```

*NOTE: be sure that the url: '/events/{eventId}' starts with '/'*

The reason is, that order decides in case, when we can treat one url two ways. And this **`url: '/events/create'`**, could really be used as the second one. *(the part 'create' as a parameter `eventId`)*

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6w6kTOBEXndB1X57zYKJ?p=preview)

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Will accept as answer as soon as I'm able to (time limit still in force)

Comment: If that helped a bit, great ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router